# How I can make my margins 2cm?

Tags: formatting, positioning, margins, double-sided

I'm new to LaTeX and was wondering how I can make my margins `2cm`?

Please note that my document needs to print double sided so I don't want to mess with the procedure LaTeX uses to enable that.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: in preamble of your document add `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`

Comment: `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`

Comment: Great minds think together!

Comment: Thanks @Zarko and Christian, I've just tried it out and it looks like it's overrided the `twoside` document class I was using. Is this what should happen?

Comment: @user5508297: Well, if it should be really twosided, the margins can't be same then, in my point of view. Are you using the `twosided` class option at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes I'm using the `twoside` doc class option. What I want is to be able to print double sided (so I need the margins to get automatically adjusted by `twoside` but I need to make sure that the margins - at the correct side of document, given the side of the paper they're on - are 2cm wide. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a `twoside` argument use the `inner=` and `outer=...` options instead of `lmargin` and `rmargin`.

I've exaggerated the values here to show the effect -- the `showframe` option is just for demonstration only.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2cm,inner=2.1cm,outer=4cm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will this also work for the `report` doc class?

Comment: @user5508297: Yes, `geometry` is very sophisticated.

Comment: Excellent. By the way, what is `\blindtext[20]` doing?

Comment: @user5508297: `\blindtext` is used to fill up the document with not really important text (just for generating pages), `\blindtext[20]` repeats the text 20 times.